# How to Store Oracle database and convert it to msaccess/excel

Tags: java, oracle, excel, ms-access, offline

i have a problem,one of my client need

a program that will connect to oracle database server,and **download/store** the table to a local file(ex; **microsoft access**) like a conversion
after that client can input an excel file and it will be added to that local file

my client want the local file/database **can be stored** offline,inside program folder
They want the program do all the job so they only give me a user&pass to their database with some example of the tables and the excel that will be inputed from the client

and the program will do the rest download the tabel,convert,input,and the last it will print the data

i know that many tutorials come with the idea to connect / update oracle with java (with OLDBC-JDBC) or open&modify msaccess file(with excel conversion)

but to combine them all?how can you do this in java?

I already saw someone do this,but in VB6
and his code is a bit messy

FYI:
the data is a **BIG** one,its use about 600.000 rows
and it is updated once per month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach you might want to explore if the desired output is MS Access is [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/).  One of the examples they give on their webpage is copying an external table into MS Access, and this is all the code you seem to need:

```
Database.open(new File("my.mdb")).copyTable("Imported", resultSet);
```

I don't have first-hand experience with that library, but it looks quite nice.

For Excel output I agree with Chris, POi is the way to go.  However, there's also a library called [jXLS](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/index.html), it's a layer on top of POI and it simplifies the creation of formatted XLS sheets a lot, check out [this sample](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/resultsetsample.html) that converts a JDBC resultset (the result of you querying Oracle) into a nicely looking Excel file.

EDIT: based on your comment on Chris' answer, if actually all you get is the db coordinates and user and pass, you'll have to:

Step 1: get the table names using [DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29), schematically like this:

```
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection (...);
DatabaseMetaData md = c.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
}
```

Step 2: iterate over the obtained list of tables and perform the table copy as shown above

Comment: omg,i am really hopeless a minute ago,
but like my question to chris,how can you download oracle tables right into excel (.xls) file?

thank you

Comment: @user115343 I am very confused now, do you want MDB or XLS or both?  And check my edit, now it also shows how to extract db metadata to get a list of tables - you don't want to hardcode the list of tables to be copied in your program.

Comment: so its like i perform a table copy from oracle to java datasource and it will convert to excel?

FYI the data is big,its about thousand

and the VB6 guys,that i mentioned above
fail in this one

sorry for my late reply,its caused by slow connection
i only need 1 file,whether it is MDB or XLS 
as long as it can store the data

Comment: Thousand records?  Or thousand tables?  If it's 1000 tables Excel is probably not the right receptacle - POI gets quite slow when you have 10000's of rows but it's quite fast with 100's or 1000's of rows.

Comment: From first-hand experience I can assure you that 1000 rows will do just fine - And don't forget to check out jXLS, what you need to do here is super simple with that library - assuming you know the table structure(s).  If not you'll have to use POI directly.

Comment: Yes i know the tables structure,ahh i forgot to mention,i got their examples,sorry for being messed up,and thanks again for being helpful

Comment: aarrrghhh,i chat with the-client again and now he said,he use about 600.000 rows

if the excel method fail(eating resource),do you have alternative?

Comment: An XLS file is limited to 65535 lines, XLSX can contain much more lines(don't know its limits without looking it up).  Newer versions of POI can manipulate XLSX files as well, but as I said, POI's performance and memory needs are seriously affected when you're manipulating lots of rows.  Maybe revert to the MDB idea or just produce a csv that can be imported into Excel?

Comment: Yes,maybe going back to MDB idea was a good one,how can you do this in java?same with copy paste thing,but this one save the data to MDB ?

Comment: aahh,i saw this VB6 guy program,he didnt combine the excel into the database,but he do this separately!!so the idea is the program will store oracle into MDB,and we can look into it and check which data will goes into print query
and another menu is the excel thing,we can import excel to program and look into it and check which data will goes into print query
the data is not combine in one storage **database** it just mix in **program** database(which is a print query)

and the client is fine with this method,they said as long as the excel can be printed,it is fine

Comment: Maybe you should also look at some reporting solution like Pentaho or Jasper, if this entire sequence is just needed to obtain a hardcopy form of part of the db that might be a more elegant solution than hopping from mdb to excel to paper?

Answer (score 1):

If only the data is needed, why not download it as excel which can be rendered pretty easily using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) ? Even excel can be served as datasource (just not MS-Access). Is your requirement only to convert it to MS-Access ? Please add more information about your problem statement.

Comment: The client want the program do all the job
they only give me a user&pass to their database

and the program will do the rest
download the tabel,convert,input,and the last it will print the data

Comment: @user115343 Well what I mean is, whether `client` wants it as only MS-Access ? or an Excel is acceptable as well ?

Comment: acceptable

like the title said

they only want,whatever it is(file)
it can modifiable and can transfer to removable media,like flashdisk

msaccess only an aproach from other people(VB6)

Comment: but how do you download oracle database and save as excel from JAVA? thank you